# Joint Probability of Events

Tags: probability

I'm reading the *Machine Learning* from K. Murphy, the section 2.2.2.2 says:

[image]

**Here is my understanding. Please correct me if anything is wrong.**

1. A and B are events, meaning that they are sets of outcomes. The joint event of A and B is another set by taking the intersection of A and B.
2. The probability of the joint event of A and B, according to the third axiom of probability, is just summing up the probabilities of all the outcomes in that intersection of A and B.
3. It is that the conditional probability is defined as $\dfrac{Pr(A \cap B)}{Pr(B)}$, not the opposite. So the second equality in equation 2.3 is a conclusion, not a definition.

**Also some confusion here:**

1. What does the *distribution* (or even joint distribution) of event(s) mean? Shouldn't we be talking about the (joint) distribution of *random variable(s)*?
2. What does it mean for an *event* $B$ to take on a value $b$: $B=b$?
3. What does *all possible states of $B$* mean? Like the outcomes contained in $B$?

Thanks. Some part of this book is just too contradictive to my previous knowledge.

Comment: I think perhaps this books identifies the random variables as events. *All possible states* just means the range of random variable. To be honest, many machine learning books have such shortcomings. They are explaining mathematics, but never like a mathematician. But if you ignore these problems, you will find it not as hard as you thought.

Comment: @BernardPan And then I start to wonder what does it even mean to compute the probability of a random variable A given another random variable B :p

Comment: Equation (2.4) pains me on a physical level. What does $\sum_b p(A,B)$ mean when there is no $b$ in the summand? What does $B=b$ mean if $B$ is an event? This textbook is actually widely used in machine learning...

Comment: @CedricSun Personally I think it actually means the (conditional/marginal/etc.) PDFs of $A$ and $B$.